# How does Android handle transformation of touch points in child views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, touch-event

When a child view is rotated, how does Android handle mapping touch points from the parent view to the child view?

Are the touch points put through a transformation at some point?  If so, where?

I know that ViewGroups have methods like:
`dispatchTouchEvent()`
`onInterceptTouchEvent()`
`onTouchEvent()`
etc.

Is one of those responsible for taking the touch point within the parent view and transforming it to the local coordinate space of a subview?

I tried looking through the source code but couldn't really understand all the interactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All this stuff is performed in `dispatchTouchEvent` method.

1. `ViewGroup` iterates through it children
2. Creating new copy of passed to `dispatchTouchEvent` `MotionEvent` for each child (**obtaining from pool** to be more precise). See `MotionEvent.obtain(MotionEvent)`
3. Offsets position of newly created `MotionEvent` using child's top and left position (see `getTop` and `getLeft` methods).
4. Applies transformation using `MotionEvent#transform` method (by taking inverse transformation matrix from child)
5. Finally, it dispatches `MotionEvent` to child (and in case when this child is also `ViewGroup` see pt.1)
6. It recycles previously obtained `MotionEvent` (see `MotionEvent#recycle`)

And yes, as **Delyan** mentioned - transformation applies only for Honeycomb and newer versions of Android. On older versions just offset is performed.

Comment: It should be noted that this only happens on Honeycomb and above since it requires the per-view transforms.

Comment: It looks like NineOldAndroids adds support for rotation - any idea how?  Seems like the ViewGroup class would truly have to be replaced for that.